# Explicit element of $(\ell^{\infty})^*  - \ell^1$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, axiom-of-choice, banach-spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s an example of a space that needs the Hahn-Banach Theorem?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5351/whats-an-example-of-a-space-that-needs-the-hahn-banach-theorem)

It is well known that the dual of $\ell^{\infty}$ properly contains $\ell^1$ (over $\mathbb{N}$, say).  For instance, any [Banach limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_limit) is an example.  However, the construction of a Banach limit that I've seen is nonconstructive: one defines the functional on a closed subspace and extends via the Hahn-Banach theorem (or some variation thereof, to bring about translation-invariance).

Nevertheless, one can see without the axiom of choice that $(\ell^{\infty})^* \neq \ell^1$, because $\ell^{\infty}$ is not separable  and therefore (I think!) its dual cannot be, while $\ell^1$ is.  However, I was recently thinking about the dual of $\ell^{\infty}$ together with the action of translation operators, and I realized I didn't have a good picture of what this object was like (though I had heard something vague about finitely additive measures).

**Question:** What's an explicit example of an element of $(\ell^{\infty})^* - \ell^1$?

Since my wondering about the nonuniqueness in the definition of Banach limits prompted this question, I also have a follow-up:

**Question$^\prime$:** Can one get a Banach limit explicitly (or at least, can one prove its existence without the axiom of choice)?

**Closed as sort-of-duplicate:** For the answer, see point #2 of Greg's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5351/whats-an-example-of-a-space-that-needs-the-hahn-banach-theorem/5477#5477) to another question.

Comment: FYI, the Hahn-Banach theorem is known to be strictly weaker than AC.  

Comment: In English:  you are looking for a bounded operator which is not L^1 ?

Comment: @John: Yes.
@Qiaochu: OK, so I guess the existence of Banach limits is also weaker than AC.

Comment: Akhil: have you looked at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/5351/whats-an-example-of-a-space-that-needs-the-hahn-banach-theorem ? I think the answers indicate (as does my hazy memory) that no such "explicit" functional exists.

Comment: In fact: although your question isn't a duplicate per se of the one I linked to, I'm not sure it's worth having both of them open. Would anyone object if I voted to close this one, perhaps after a link is added to the older question? Or have I misunderstood Akhil's question?

Comment: Is this really equivalent to the axiom of choice?

Comment: John: do you mean this specific question, or the general question about Hahn-Banach?

Comment: @Yemon: Yes, I think point #2 in Greg Kuperberg's answer constitutes an answer to this question.  

Comment: @Qiaochu: Thought so. Well, we may as well wait a while for Akhil's feedback.

Comment: Well, am casting vote to close, in line with previous comments. Though I will be happy to vote for re-opening if good reasons are pointed out.

Comment: Akhil, generally one identifies $\ell_\infty$ with the continuous functions on $\beta(N)$, the Stone-Cech compactification of the natural numbers, so that $\ell_\infty^*$ is identified with the finite signed measures on $\beta(N)$.  However, it is not hard to check that $\ell_\infty^*$ can also be identified with the finitely additive finite set functions on the natural numbers. See, e.g., Example 8 and  Problem 36 in Section 6.4 of A. Wilansky "Functional Analysis". 

Comment: @Yemon: Thank you for the pointer to Greg Kuperberg's answer (which is relevant). I have also voted to close now.

Comment: This should be the model for how a question gets closed!

Comment: Just to point out a possibly false assumption in the question, regarding the theorem that if $X$ is not separable then neither is $X^*$.  The proof I know of this fact makes use of the Hahn-Banach theorem.  So I don't think this is a choice-free way to see that $(\ell^\infty)^* - \ell^1$ is nonempty, and the other answers strongly suggest that the fact requires some version of AC.

Comment: @Nate: OK, makes sense (I can't remember a proof of the assertion offhand).