# Generalized limits on $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, lo.logic, set-theory, real-analysis, axiom-of-choice

Let $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ denote the set of bounded real sequences $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. The $\lim$ operator is a *partial* linear operator from $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ to $\mathbb{R}$. With the [Hahn-Banach theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem), $\lim$ can be extended to a *generalized limit functional*. The Hahn-Banach theorem uses the Axiom of Choice.

Are there models of $\mathsf{ZF}$ in which no generalized limit functionals exist?

Comment: Can we use the generalized limits of $0/1$-valued sequences to produce a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$? If so, then the answer is yes, since if ZF is consistent, then there are models of ZF with no nonprincipal ultrafilters.

Comment: Some posts which seem related: [Explicit element of $(\ell^{\infty})^*  - \ell^1$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/22661), [What's an example of a space that needs the Hahn-Banach Theorem?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/5351), [$\ell^1$ vs. continuous dual of $\ell^{\infty}$ in ZF+AD](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/103476), [Nonnegative linear functionals over $l^\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55651)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins All nonprincipal ultrafilters create generalised limits, but not all generalised limits come from ultrafilters.  I myself was a little confused about this point, so I wrote a blog post recently in part to sort things out in my head once and for all: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2017/05/11/generalisations-of-the-limit-functional/ .  There I also note that generalised limits can be used to create nonmeasurable sets and hence do not exist in Solovay models.

Comment: @TerryTao When you write "not all generalised limits come from ultrafilters" you mean that not every $f\in\ell_\infty^*$ which extends the usual limit, is of the form $f(x)=\operatorname{\mathscr{U}-lim} x_n$ for some ultrafilter $\mathscr U$, i.e., not all elements of $\ell_\infty^*$ are ultralimits, right? IIRC all such funtionals are in the closed convex hull of the set of ultralimits, which is also a possible interpretation of the phrase "come from ultrafilter". (Everything I write here is in ZFC, I guess that detailed analysis how much choice is needed is probably not simple.)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I posted this question on math.SE, inspired basically by your comment about generalized limits and nonprincipal ultrafilters: [Does existence of some (nice) non-trivial functionals in $\ell_\infty^*\setminus\ell_1$ give a free ultrafilter on $\omega$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2288742)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes.  In fact, if you work in $\mathsf{ZF}+\mathsf{DC}+$ "all sets of reals have the property of Baire" ($\mathsf{BP}$), say the [Solovay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovay_model) or Shelah models, you can prove that $(\ell^\infty)^* = \ell^1$, so that the only continuous linear functionals on $\ell^\infty$ are those coming from $\ell^1$.  The generalized limits are certainly not of this form, since they vanish on $c_0$ but not identically.  Under these axioms, $\ell^1$ is reflexive.

You can find a proof in Schechter, *Handbook of Analysis and its Foundations*, [sections 29.37–38](https://books.google.com/books?id=eqUv3Bcd56EC&pg=PA810).

Interestingly, under these axioms all linear functionals on any Banach space are continuous, so in fact the *algebraic* dual of $\ell^\infty$ also equals $\ell^1$.  And the limit operator has no linear extension to $\ell^\infty$.

Digression: This is a fun example because there are several different ways to prove in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that $(\ell^\infty)^* \ne \ell^1$.  It is interesting to see how all of them fail in this model, and where they used choice. For instance:

1. Use Hahn-Banach as in your example.  Hahn-Banach doesn't work without choice.
2. Use Alaoglu's theorem to produce a weak-* limit point of the usual basis $\{e_i\}$ of $\ell^1 \subset (\ell^\infty)^*$.  This is another sort of generalized limit.  So Alaoglu also must fail without choice; of course, the usual proof uses Tychonoff.
3. Recall the following exercise: "If $X^*$ is separable then so is $X$." Note that $\ell^1$ is separable and $\ell^\infty$ is not.  But the "exercise" used Hahn-Banach, and isn't necessarily true without choice.

Comment: About your digression: I cannot resist to mention another possibility, which is using limit along an ultrafilter. BTW perhaps you could post the proof using Banach-Alaoglu's theorem here: [Dual of $l^\infty$ is not $l^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/868787). (It seems that such proof has not been posted there yet, Arguments based on separability and Hahn-Banach theorem are among the answers.)