# A separable Banach space and a non-separable Banach space having the same dual space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I asked myself the following question when I was student just for curiosity. I asked a bit around (my professor, some researchers that I know), but nobody was able to give me an answer. So maybe it is just that nobody thought enough about that, or maybe it is not a stupid question.

**Question:** Do there exist two Banach spaces, one separable and one non-separable, having isomorphic dual spaces?

Note: isomorphic in the sense that there exists a linear homeomorphism between the two.

Comment: If you're willing to accept the negation of the axiom of choice, see the answers to this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/5351/whats-an-example-of-a-space-that-needs-the-hahn-banach-theorem/

Comment: I tried to open that link twice and each time my laptop gets mad!! Anyway... ehm, actually I use Zorn's lemma every day..

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The duals of $C[0,1]$ and of $C[0,1]\oplus_\infty c_0(\Bbb{R})$ are isometrically isomorphic.

Comment: Beautifully simple!  (At least, if you take the Riesz representation theorem for $C[0,1]^*$ for granted.)

Comment: Professor Johnson, what would be a relatively up to date reference for studying the question of what spaces are duals? I have some survey papers but they are a few decades old.

Comment: Your question is too broad, Andres.  Do you have something more specific in mind?  

Comment: I agree Mark! When Bill's answer appeared whilst I was writing mine, I couldn't believe I didn't think of that instead.

Comment: Andres, although it doesn't tell you which Banach spaces are duals and which are not, if you're wondering whether a given Banach space is a dual space you could look at finding a suitable compact topology on the unit ball, as in Sten Kaijser's paper *A note on dual Banach spaces*, Math. Scand. **41** (1977), 325--330.

Comment: Andres, maybe you are interested in knowing a classical result that says that a von Neumann algebra is always a dual space and the predual is basically unique. This is why there is no hope to find an example for my question using $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: @Valerio, thanks. It was something like this I was wondering about. @Philip: Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 13):

The James Tree space $JT$ and $JT \oplus_2 \ell_2(2^{\aleph_0})$ have isomorphic duals.

Comment: Thannk you! Can you please tell me what is the James tree space?

Comment: Valerio, the book *Topics in Banach Space Theory* by Albiac and Kalton contains lots of the information that you are after, including the definition of the James Tree space. You mentioned in a comment to Bill Johnson's answer that you want to know which spaces are duals; obviously reflexive spaces are, and it is classical (I think due to Civin and Yood?) that quasi-reflexive spaces are duals of quasi-reflexive spaces. Note that a dual space is complemented in its bidual, so for example you can show that $c_0$ is not a dual space by showing that it is not complemented in $\ell_\inty = c_0^{**}$

Comment: That $c_0$ is not complemented in $\ell_\infty$ is shown in the Albiac-Kalton book, but they also give a proof that $c_0$ is not linearly homeomorphic to a subspace of a separable dual space (so therefore isn't a dual itself). They also give a proof that $L_1[0,1]$ does not embed in a separable dual, so $L_1[0,1]$ is not a dual either. Despite this, $L_1[0,1]$ is in fact complemented in its bidual. I strongly recommend the Albiac-Kalton book.

Comment: Sorry Valerio, I now see that it was someone else (Andres Caicedo) who asked about a reference for dual spaces.

Comment: don't worry, it's always important to have the opportunity to learn something. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, among classical Banach spaces,
 $c_0,$ C[a,b], $L_1[a,b],$ $l_{\infty}/c_0$ are not dual.