# Infinite dimensional vector spaces with compact unit ball

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{K}$. Suppose that $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is a complete normed vector space, in the sense that any Cauchy sequence is convergent. Suppose that the closed unit ball of $X$ is compact in the strong topology.

**Question 1.**
Is $X$ necessarily isomorphic to some finite dimensional Banach space ?

**Question 2.** If the answer for the question 1 is  **no** , can we always find in $\mathcal{L}(X,X)$ an unbounded linear operator ?

Different from this question [Is there an infinite-dimensional Banach space with a compact unit ball?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77750/is-there-an-infinite-dimensional-banach-space-with-a-compact-unit-ball) I would like to assume the axiom of choice.

**Comment.** 
The example I have in mind is $(\mathbb{R}^n,\|\cdot\|_{2})$ as $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space. 
Clearly 
$\text{dim}_{\mathbb{Q}}\ \mathbb{R}^n=\infty$ and the unit ball is compact and this space is complete with respect to the standard Euclidean norm $\|\cdot\|_2$, but in this example both questions 1 and 2 are trivial.

Comment: "would like _to_ assume the"

Comment: @Ricky thanks for point this correction.


Comment: I think I don't fully understand what a "norm" over a general field $\mathbb K$ is...???

Comment: And, by "strong topology" do you just mean "norm topology"?

Comment: @Matthew as you noted the field $\mathbb{K}$ will be not so general, we have to suppose that there exist a modulus function defined on it. 

Comment: Sure, and the norm should take values on the positive elements of 
$\mathbb K$ for the definition to work. Your example does not fulfill this condition.

Comment: @Xabier why my example does not fulfill the conditions ?

Comment: @Leandro: Sorry, I got it wrong. There is such a thing as a normed space over a field other than $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C.$ You need a valuation on your field (what you call a modulus function, I guess). The valuation takes values on $[0,\infty)\subset \mathbb R$, the same as the norm. So, it makes sense to regard (say) $\mathbb R$ as a $\mathbb Q$-vector space, and $x\mapsto |x|$ is a norm on this $\mathbb Q$-vector space. 



Comment: I think that you need to start with a complete base field, though. 

Comment: I liked your question, Leandro! I had never thought of $\mathbb{R}$ as a infinite dimensional space with compact unit ball! You opened my mind a bit! :-) +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the following meets your setup.  Let $\mathbb K = \mathbb Z_2$ with the "absolute value" $|0|=0, |1|=1$ (this is non-Archimedean).  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value_%28algebra%29

Set $V = \mathbb Z_2^I$ for some index set $I$, with the trivial norm $\|0\|=0$ and $\|x\|=1$ for all other vectors $x$.  This satisfies the usual rules, with $\|kx\| = |k|\|x\|$ for $k\in\mathbb K, x\in V$.  Clearly $V$ actually have the discrete metric, and so is complete.  Now, the closed unit ball is all of $V$, and not compact if $I$ is infinite.

BUT, I could instead define $\|x\|=2$ for $x\not=0$.  Still we have a norm.  Now the closed unit ball is $\{0\}$; and so is compact.  All non-trivial linear maps have norm $1$.

To me, this seems like a very, very silly example, which perhaps shows that the original question needs tweaking with a bit...

If you start with an Archimedean absolute value, then really you have a subfield of $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb R$ (which must contain $\mathbb Q$).  By continuity, I then think you can turn $V$ into a $\mathbb R$ vector space, with a "norm" in the usual sense.  Then if $V$ has a compact unit ball, it must be finite dimensional (over $\mathbb R$).  So your example of $\mathbb R^2$ over $\mathbb Q$ is in a sense all that can happen.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for the example. The last paragraph I have to think a bit more. Anyway your example answer the question since I did not made any assumptions on the norm. 